# Access restriction on sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11

Tags: java, security, provider, smartcard, pkcs#11

I'm trying to setup a PKCS11 provider for accessing a smartcard.
I installed a PKCS11 library on my system and followed the instructions in the [Java PKCS#11 Reference Guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/p11guide.html).
In the reference they simply create an instance of `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11` and pass the name of the configuration file to the constructor.
When I try to compile the following code

```
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11("pkcs11.cfg");
Security.addProvider(p);
```

I get the following error.

> Access restriction: The constructor SunPKCS11(String) is not accessible due to restriction on required library /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar

What am I doing wrong?
I use Eclipse 3.5 with Java SE 1.6 under Ubuntu x86.

Best regards.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Look into the projects's properties and open the `Libraries` tab. I assume you have set the `JRE System Library` to an execution environment. Change it to the workspace JRE or select a specific JRE manually.

Background:
By selecting an execution environment you say that you want to write an app that is compliant to the Java API. The class `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11` is located in the sun package which marks it as proprietary to Sun Java implementation and is not part of the standard Java API.

Comment: Changing from the JRE System Library to the workspace JRE led the warning disappear. Thanx!

Comment: @sssvrock You are still using java 1.6? Because this answer is dedicated for that version. For newer java versions (especialyl Java 11+) you most likely need a different approach.

Answer (score 9):

Go to your project properties, *Java Build Path* pane, and expand the JRE System Library entry.  Click *Access rules* and click the Edit... button.  Add an Access Rule that makes **Accessible** the Rule Pattern **sun/security/pkcs11/****.  This will make Eclipse stop whining.

Answer (score 6):

There is one other cause if you use a `64 bit runtime on Windows`. In that case, the necessary classes are simply not present.

Solution: Use a 32 bit runtime.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6880559

Answer (score 5):

As far as I have come to understand, there are two ways of using PKCS#11 tokens in Java: using the Sun APIs, and using some proprietary implementation. Each has its advantages and disadvantages.
Sun'API main advantage is that it maps PKCS#11 tokens onto regular KeyStores. BouncyCastle can thus access the private keys in the token without actually figuring out that it is interacting with an hardware device. Moreover any native dependency is already bundled with Sun's JVM, and you don't have to worry about porting or supporting native code on different platforms. The main disadvantage is that it is non standard, so you are not guaranteed to find it on any JVM.
The commercial APIs (see IAIK's PKCS11 wrapper) are good, and even open sourced, but they have two disadvantages: they are made to work with another API (which you have to pay for...), so they do not expose the token as a KeyStore and you cannot use BouncyCastle transparently, and they have a native component which you have to maintain and distribute. If you have to work with PKCS#11 in a browser, you know what a pain that is...

Answer (score 4):

The reason for that error is certain classes are only suppose to be used by the Sun JVM and with newer versions of Eclipse a warning check was put in to warn the developer of improper/illegal use of classes.

Another stackoverflow thread recommends using the Bouncy Castle implementation.
[Weird problem using sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11: The specified procedure could not be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692509/weird-problem-using-sun-security-pkcs11-sunpkcs11-the-specified-procedure-could)

Comment: But when it's not ok to use this class, why is it used in the reference guide and what would be a llegal way of dynamicly loading a PKCS 11 provider?

Comment: I already read this article. But in this article http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.bouncy-castle.devel/2060 I read that Bouncycastle doesn't support the PKCS11.

Comment: Bouncy Castle is an alternative Java Cryptography Provider and Library, that's why it is not restricted by Oracle (Sun) on "out of the box" use.